# Styling some Wordpress polylang data

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

I want to style the (at the moment) 2 arrays with some CSS.

I've some code:

```
<ul id="flags">
    <?php pll_the_languages(array('show_flags'=>1, 'show_names'=>0)); ?>
</ul>
```

How can I do this?
Edit: Sorry, I forgot the question. I need to style every array individually, so array 1 get color blue, array 2 color black..

Comment: How about putting a style in the UL tag where you're array is inside of?

Comment: Styling an array is not a phrase which makes much sense.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I need to style every array individually, so array 1 get color blue, array 2 get color black..

Comment: Not 100% sure to understand your needs, but I've tried an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39527824/4927984).

Answer (score 0):

It seems your arrays have differents IDs. You can work with this:

Apply to your IDs some CSS as follow:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="flags">...</ul>
<ul id="flags2">...</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#flags {
    background-color: red;
}

#flags2 {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it dosen't work with my problem, because the php send me 2 times 2 arrays out `code`<ul id="flags">
<?php pll_the_languages(array('show_flags'=>0, 'show_names'=>0)); ?></ul>
<ul id="flags2">
<?php pll_the_languages(array('show_flags'=>1, 'show_names'=>0)); ?>
</ul>

Comment: Are the IDs of your arrays differents? Can't you set a CSS class somewhere on the code sent?

Comment: Rewrote my answer, hope it will bring you some help

Comment: The php in the html send 2 textes out, and if I add two ul, it will give out 4 textes instead of 2 textes, that is the problem on your code. I need a solution, that I style array 1 and array 2 with 1 ul.

Comment: Can you provide us the HTML code (or a part) **generated** by this PHP function?